# Conversion of Fbx or Obj to Cesium Tiling

Tags: software-recommendations, cesium, 3d-model, photogrammetry

I have a an **OBJ** File and a **FBX** File of very large size (OBJ = 25GB & FBX = 6GB)

I'm looking for a way to convert either of them into Cesium Tile Format. I have tried using *Pix4D software* which is capable of converting it but it reduces the model quality significantly.

Can yousuggest something that doesn't affect the quality much?